# Arraylist Java showing out index out of bounds

Tags: java, arraylist

My goal is to create a new instance where the first 2 elements are the original elements and after that is the median of last 3 elements.For example, `[5,2,9,1,7,4,6,3,8]` becomes `[5,2,5,2,7,4,6,4,6]`.

My way to solve this problem is to create 2 new array lists where one is the subarray between 3 elements starting from index 2 and having `(i-2,i+1)`, sort and lastly get the index 1 of the new subarray into my  new array list. However this runs into an index out of bounds error.

```
import java.util.*;

 public class P2J4
{
    public static void main (String[]args){
       List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(16, 42, 99, 17, 2);
       ArrayList<Integer>newarr=new ArrayList<>();
       newarr.add(0,items.get(0));
       newarr.add(1,items.get(1));
    
       for(int i=2;i<items.size();i++){
          
           List<Integer> sub = items.subList(i-2,i+1);
      
           Collections.sort(sub);
           newarr.set(i,sub.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList.set` only updates existing elements. It does not append elements if the given index is out of bounds. You need to use `ArrayList.add` or add enough elements beforehand so that `newarr.size() == items.size()`

```
newarr.add(sub.get(1));
```

```
import java.util.*;

 public class P2J4
{
    public static void main (String[]args){
       List<Integer> items = Arrays.asList(16, 42, 99, 17, 2);
       ArrayList<Integer>newarr=new ArrayList<>();
       newarr.add(0,items.get(0));
       newarr.add(1,items.get(1));
    
       for(int i=2;i<items.size();i++){
          
           List<Integer> sub = items.subList(i-2,i+1);
      
           Collections.sort(sub);
           newarr.add(sub.get(1));
        }
    }
}
```